# Call a function that returns a number as fn(10) or fn * 10

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a function that returns the number of days in milliseconds that can be invoked in the following two forms:

```
days(7) // Expected output 604800000
days * 7 // Expected output 604800000
```

The code below works but modifies the Function prototype:

```
Function.prototype.valueOf = function() {
    return this();
}
Function.prototype.toString = function() {
    return this.valueOf().toString();
}

const d = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
const days = function (n) { return n && n * d || d}

console.log(days(7)); // 604800000
console.log(days * 7); // 604800000

console.log(days.toString(), `${days}`) // 86400000 86400000
console.log(days) // [λ: days]
```

Despite a number of approaches I am unable to make this work without modifying the prototype. Here is one attempt for reference. ( I also tried using a proxy )

```
const d = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24

function Days() {
    return function (n) { return n && n * d || d}
} 

Days.prototype.valueOf = function() {
    return this();
}
Days.prototype.toString = function() {
    return this.valueOf().toString();
}

const days = new Days()

console.log(days(7)); // 604800000
console.log(days * 7); // NaN

console.log(days.toString(), `${days}`) // function (n) { var $_$c = $_$wf(1);  ...
console.log(days) // [λ]
```

Thanks in anticipation!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take a closure over a function which returns a value with the parameter and implement a `toString` function which returns the value of one day.

```js
const days = (d => {
    function f(n) {
        return n * d;
    }
    f.toString = function () { return d; };
    return f;
})(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);

console.log(days(7))   // 604800000
console.log(days * 7); // 604800000
```

Comment: Thanks Nina, I noticed that `${days}` returns `86400000` i.e with backticks so I amended to  f.valueOf = function () { return d; };   f.toString = function () { return f.valueOf().toString(); };

Answer (score 0):

```js
class Day {
  constructor(days = 1) {
    this.days = days;
  }
  
  toString() {
    return Day * this.days;
  }

  static toString() {    
    return 86400000;
  }
}

const sevenDays = new Day(7);

console.log(sevenDays); // { "days": 7 }
console.log(`${sevenDays}`); // 604800000
console.log(Day); // 1 Day (default) = 86400000
console.log(Day * 2); // 2 Days = 172800000
console.log(7 * Day); // 7 Days = 604800000
console.log(Day + 86400000 + 86400000); // 3 Days = 259200000
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Nina Scholz this is what i implemented:

```
const makeUnit = u => function (d) {
    const f = n => n * d
    f.valueOf = () => d
    f.toString = () => f.valueOf().toString()
    return f;
}(u);

const seconds = makeUnit(1000)
const minutes = makeUnit(seconds * 60)
const hours = makeUnit(minutes * 60)
const days = makeUnit(hours * 24)
const weeks = makeUnit(days * 7)

console.log(seconds(1)) // 1000
console.log(minutes(1)) // 60000
console.log(hours(1))   // 3600000
console.log(days(1))    // 86400000
console.log(weeks(1))   // 604800000

console.log(seconds * 1) // 1000
console.log(minutes * 1) // 60000
console.log(hours * 1)  // 3600000
console.log(days * 1)   // 86400000
console.log(weeks * 1)  // 604800000

console.log(days.toString(), `${days}`) // 86400000 86400000
```